# How to copy the logs of Azure devops Pipeline logs automatically into storage account?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-storage, azure-pipelines

I need to upload the logs of my Azure DevOps pipeline to my Azure storage account.

To copy a file to a storage account Azure DevOps has the task Azcopy.

For my build, I had an artifact that I can copy to the storage account.

For my build with the task 'Publish artifact' which will publish the artifacts to the Azure DevOps git repo. And in the next step copy the files to Azure storage account.

Is there any way to publish the logs of a pipeline to the git repo (of Azure DevOps) or directly copy it to the storage account with (AZcopy)?

Comment: *I need to upload the logs of my Azure DevOps pipeline to my Azure storage account.* Why?

Comment: I use a task called Azsk which will give me a result in a csv format.
Now i have to download the logs unzip the folder go inside the some file structure and get the reports. But I was wondering if it was possible to upload the 'download the logs to zip' to a storage account so i can run my pipeline automatically and have the logs inside a storage account